# Python SQLAlchemy: Row limit to store to PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy in Python3 to store pandas dataframes to PostreSQL table. Things work until 78M rows to store, things work with 20M rows but

```
Got 75032111 rows.

Total time taken 11222.68 s.
Finished at 2018-05-04 06:07:34.
Killed
```

where the storing gets killed. I use the SQLAlechemy command `df.to_sql(dbName, engine)`.

**Is there some limit to store data to PSQL database with SQLAlchemy in Python? What is the preferred way to store big tables, some sync command to continue storing if things get intercepted because of large size?**

Comment: Maybe your process was OOM killed? One way to store potentially huge amounts of data to Postgresql is to use the COPY command, but then you'd have to convert your data to a suitable format, though you could do it generatively.

Comment: Run `dmesg` and see if that is exactly the case.  Will be a very apparent spam that says it killed Python.

Comment: @metatoaster temperatures of my CPUs are getting too high when operating with very large files, potentially killing some operations but I was able to solve this problem with the answer below with `chunksize=100000`, dunno about heat problem, have to monitor it. Thank you for helping to figure it out +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't hit this limit before, but what you could do is insert by batches using:

```
df.to_sql(dbName, engine, chunksize=100000)  # alter chunksize to your liking
```

Comment: This fixed the issue but `dmesg` reveals that the temperatures of my CPUs are getting too high when doing the heavy lifting on very large files +1

Comment: I think that's natural since your CPUs have to do the inserts to the db. Did you try altering the chunksize to see if that alleviates the temps? (e.g. `chunksize=10000`).